# Facing issues while converting stored procedure into entity framework function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am new to entity framework. I have a procedure which save shipment data and I have to convert that procedure into entity framework function. For simple insert/update I am able to use entity framework but for this particular procedure I am facing issue.

In below procedure I have to update shipment table which have addressId, shipmenStatusId and serviceId as a foreign key. For particular shipment record if address is already exists then add existing address id in foreign key column otherwise first add new address into address table and then pick newly address id and update it into shipment address id column and same step for shipmentStatusType and service type.

Here is my procedure script.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spSavePackage
@TrackingNbr VARCHAR(50),
@Carrier VARCHAR(10),
@PackageType VARCHAR(20) = NULL,
@ShippedDate DATETIME = NULL,
@ScheduledDate DATETIME = NULL,
@AddressLine1 VARCHAR(50)= NULL,
@AddressLine2 VARCHAR(50)= NULL,
@City VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@State VARCHAR(2) = NULL,
@Country VARCHAR(2) = NULL,
@StatusDescription VARCHAR(50) = NULL 
AS

BEGIN

    DECLARE @AddressId int, @DeliveryStatusId int , @PackageId int

    IF EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM tblPackages WHERE TrackingNr = @TrackingNbr AND Carrier = @Carrier)
    BEGIN   
        IF EXISTS(SELECT Id FROM tblDeliveryAddress WHERE Address1 = @AddressLine1 AND Address2 = @AddressLine2
                    AND City = @City AND State = @State AND Country = @Country)
        BEGIN
            SELECT @AddressId = Id FROM tblDeliveryAddress WHERE Address1 = @AddressLine1 AND Address2 = @AddressLine2
                    AND City = @City AND State = @State AND Country = @Country
        END         
        ELSE            
        BEGIN
            SELECT @AddressId = MAX(Id) from tblDeliveryAddress
            SET @AddressId = @AddressId + 1

            INSERT INTO tblDeliveryAddress VALUES(@AddressId , @AddressLine1 , @AddressLine2 , @City , @State , @Country)   
        END

        IF EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM tblDeliveryStatus WHERE Status = @StatusDescription)
        BEGIN
            SELECT @DeliveryStatusId = Id FROM tblDeliveryStatus WHERE Status = @StatusDescription
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @DeliveryStatusId = MAX(Id) FROM tblDeliveryStatus
            SET @DeliveryStatusId = @DeliveryStatusId + 1

            INSERT INTO tblDeliveryStatus VALUES(@DeliveryStatusId , @StatusDescription)
        END

        UPDATE tblPackages
        SET DeliveryAddressID = @AddressId, DeliveryStatusId = @DeliveryStatusId,
        ShippedDate = @ShippedDate , PackageType = @PackageType, ScheduledDate = @ScheduledDate
        WHERE TrackingNr = @TrackingNbr AND Carrier = @Carrier
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @PackageId = MAX(Id) FROM tblPackages
        SET @PackageId = @PackageId + 1
        INSERT INTO tblPackages(Id , TrackingNr , Carrier) VALUES (@PackageId , @TrackingNbr , @Carrier)
    END 
END
```

For implementing functionality of this procedure I had created written following EF code.

```
public void UpdateShipments(List<Tuple<tblShipment, List<tblActivity>>> shipments)
    {
        tblShipment shipment = null;
        var manager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this._context).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
        foreach (var tuple in shipments)
        {
            shipment = tuple.Item1;

            if (shipment.ConsigneeAddress != null)
            {
                shipment.ConsigneeAddressId = this.AddAddress(shipment.ConsigneeAddress).ID;
                shipment.ConsigneeAddress = null;
            }
            else
            {
                shipment.ConsigneeAddressId = null;
                shipment.ConsigneeAddress = null;
            }

            if (shipment.ShipperAddress != null)
            {
                shipment.ShipperAddressId = this.AddAddress(shipment.ShipperAddress).ID;
                shipment.ShipperAddress = null;
            }
            else
            {
                shipment.ShipperAddressId = null;
                shipment.ShipperAddress = null;
            }

            if (shipment.Service != null)
            {
                shipment.ServiceId = this.AddService(shipment.Service).ID;
                shipment.Service = null;
            }
            else
            {
                shipment.ServiceId = null;
                shipment.Service = null;
            }

            if (shipment.ShipmentStatusType != null)
            {
                shipment.ShipmentStatusId = this.AddStatusType(shipment.ShipmentStatusType).ID;
                shipment.ShipmentStatusType = null;
            }
            else
            {
                shipment.ShipmentStatusId = null;
                shipment.ShipmentStatusType = null;
            }

            this._context.Entry(shipment).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
        this._context.SaveChanges();
    }


public tblAddressType AddAddressType(tblAddressType addressType)
    {
        tblAddressType tempAddressType = (from m in this._context.AddressTypes
                                          where m.Type.ToUpper() == addressType.Type.ToUpper()
                                          select m).FirstOrDefault();
        if (tempAddressType == null)
        {
            tempAddressType = this._context.AddressTypes.Add(addressType);
            this._context.SaveChanges();
        }

        return tempAddressType;
    }

    public tblAddress AddAddress(tblAddress address)
    {
        tblAddress tempAddress = (from m in this._context.Addresses
                                  where m.AddressLine1.ToUpper() == address.AddressLine1.ToUpper() && m.AddressLine2.ToUpper() == address.AddressLine2.ToUpper() && m.City.ToUpper() == address.City.ToUpper()
                       && m.StateProvinceCode.ToUpper() == address.StateProvinceCode.ToUpper() && m.CountryCode.ToUpper() == address.CountryCode.ToUpper()
                                  select m).FirstOrDefault();

        if (tempAddress == null)
        {
            address.AddressType = this.AddAddressType(address.AddressType);
            address.AddressTypeId = address.AddressType.ID;
            address.AddressType = null;
            tempAddress = this._context.Addresses.Add(address);
            this._context.SaveChanges();
        }

        return tempAddress;
    }
```

After spending lots of time I found this way to implement it but I am not satisfied with this implementation. As I have to do lot's of hit for saving/updating shipment records which slowing the process. I need some optimized way to update shipment records so that for saving records I have to do only single database hit. I have multiple shipments record(records which is in collection) and I want single database hit to save records or 1 database hit to save one shipment records.

I tried to clarify my problems if any one facing issue to understand it then let me know. I am using c# as a programming language, sql server as a database and entity framework 6.0 as ORM.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Awadhendra

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem in the past.
While it probably would be considered a hack by some others due to the nature of hard coding things that may change, if you also implement even simple integration tests (see later for an example) it is possible to keep track of such changes

Here is my solution

```
namespace ContextNamespace
{
    public partial class ContextClass
    {
      public Task UpdateShipments(List<Tuple<tblShipment,
                                        List<tblActivity>>> shipments)
      {
        return this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("EXEC spSavePackage @p1 = @p1..", 
               new SqlParameter("@p1", shipments.???),....);
       }
    }
}
```

Along side this I have integration tests like this one, that their purpose is only to pass without exceptions -of course they can easily be fleshed out to include more proper checks

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Sproc_Test()
    {
        //Create object
        Context context = new Context();
        await context.UpdateShipments(/*object*/);
    }
```

An example of use in code is like this

```
 public Task DoSomething(Object data)
 {
     return Context.UpdateShipments(data);
 }
```

Comment: I don't want to execute procedure by EF. I want to convert above procedure code into EF code.

Comment: I am sorry, I guess I missed that when the question was read. Here is a link to a library that might be helpful [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended)

Comment: If you will see in code above paste by me then it is trying to update/insert on multiple tables. The links which you given is for batch update/insert for single table not for multiple table.

Comment: I am sorry, it seems that I do not know this well enough to properly help you, but I will try and pass it along to someone who can

Comment: I don't have a way to test it right now, but what happens if you simply remove the calls to this._context.SaveChanges() in the inner functions? You can optionally add a boolean parameter indicating if the helper function should save or not